# Boost: Although compiled, missing lib

Tags: visual-c++, boost, linker-errors

I've compiled Boost and am using it in a Visual C++ project. At some point, I started getting the following error:

```
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_filesystem-vc100-mt-sgd-1_45.lib'
```

AFAIK I have the linker configuration set correctly. I've searched for the lib and found a few close matches:

```
$(LIB_BOOST)\stage\lib\libboost_filesystem-vc100-mt-gd-1_45.lib
$(LIB_BOOST)\stage\lib\libboost_filesystem-vc100-mt-gd.lib
$(LIB_BOOST)\stage\lib\libboost_filesystem-vc100-mt-1_45.lib
$(LIB_BOOST)\stage\lib\libboost_filesystem-vc100-mt.lib
$(LIB_BOOST)\bin.v2\libs\filesystem\build\msvc-10.0\release\link-static\threading-multi\libboost_filesystem-vc100-mt-1_45.lib
$(LIB_BOOST)\bin.v2\libs\filesystem\build\msvc-10.0\debug\link-static\threading-multi\libboost_filesystem-vc100-mt-gd-1_45.lib
```

(Notice the missing 's' in most of them)

What does the missing 's' represent? What do these similar yet different libs stand for? How come I'm missing it although I've compiled all of Boost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

's' is one of [ABI tags](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#library-naming)

> ABI tag: encodes details that affect
>   the library's interoperability with
>   other compiled code. For each such
>   feature, a single letter is added to
>   the tag:

```
    Key     Use this library when:
    s   linking statically to the C++ standard library and compiler runtime support libraries.
    g   using debug versions of the standard and runtime support libraries.
    y   using a special debug build of Python.
    d   building a debug version of your code.7
    p   using the STLPort standard library rather than the default one supplied with your compiler.
    n   using STLPort's deprecated “native iostreams” feature.8
```

> For example, if you build a debug
>   version of your code for use with
>   debug versions of the static runtime
>   library and the STLPort standard
>   library in “native iostreams” mode,
>   the tag would be: -sgdpn. If none of
>   the above apply, the ABI tag is
>   ommitted.

Comment: Following your pointer, I reinstalled Boost using BoostPro Installer. I chose to install both static\debug\multithreaded and both static\multithreaded. Indeed I was not missing the library afterwards.

Comment: @Jonathan: if you build the boost libraries with --build-type=complete then it will build all supported variants. See section "5.3.4 Invoke bjam" in http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#invoke-bjam

Answer (score 1):

I added command line option: runtime-link=shared,static
That included the missing s files.

Hope it helps